# Problems with Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets

I have had problems with Ethereum Wallet for a couple weeks. It started after not synching for a while due to travelling. When I got back online, it needed to sync a lot and it got really slow. After a few days I kept getting errors that it couldn't connect without anything more in the logs. I read somewhere that I had to remove the chaindata and let it sync from scratch. Have done that, but after syncing to near completion, I still couldn't see the content of my wallet (confirmed that it holds coins on etherchain.org) and it slowed down. When I restarted the wallet I got the following error:

> Unable to connect. Please start geth with the following options:
>
> geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "file://"
>
> Optional add: --unlock .

* I have no idea how this would be done. CLI? from where?

I'm using Windows 10/Ethereum Wallet 0.8.10 and have had no significant problems before (besides the ones that disappear upon a restart).

This is all very frustrating. I have a significant amount of money in my wallet and even though I plan to keep it that way the idea that my money is inaccessible is not fun. How can I fix this? I'm completely stumped as to what I can do more. Are there any other offline wallets I could move to and how (since I'm pretty much locked out of the Ethereum Wallet software)? Thanks for your suggestions and time in advance.

Comment: Do you realy need a full node? Downlaod Etherwallet and open it locally https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.8.9 With the private key you can see/send your ether via etherwallet too.

Comment: I don't need a full node. Like to contribute, but if it comes at the price of not being able to do anything with it, I choose not to. Thanks for the response will report back if I got it to work.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. Interesting to see how it all fits together. This is code I can read, so will dive into this etherwallet to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Etherwallet:

Download Etherwallet and open index.html locally with your browser:

https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/latest

With the private key you can see/send your ether via local etherwallet instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying for a week now with the same issues. Uninstalling ,reinstalling, deleting blockchain over and over for the testnet.Main network would never download.
Used geth --fast and it told me my time was out by 57.something seconds. I had tried gist.gov and Microsoft time over and over. When i went in and changed the clock manually by around 57 secs, the blocks started pouring in.
I believe yours and everyone else's problem is the timing sync not the wallet software or config.
Try geth --fast and see what your response is in regard to the time warning. I would bet its the same as my issue.

A week people, but i persevered,tried every possible combination of answers here but it was the clock all along. Good luck everyone. Hope this helped.