# How to sign a transaction on an offline computer?

Tags: cold-storage, offline

Short version: Is there a way to sign a transaction on an offline-computer **using only official or widely trusted tools?**

Long version of this question: There are several posts on how to do that but all of them link to more or less experimental tools. Is there a way to sign a transaction using only widely trusted tools like `geth` and move it already signed as a file via USB-stick to an online-computer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use MyEtherWallet `offline signing` on airgapped computer.  https://www.myetherwallet.com/#offline-transaction

Answer (score 1):

I created a small script for this that uses node and web3.

It's at https://gist.github.com/neuhaus/7387edf411513a9f11f1242dcec8d62e

Comment: thanks. I have some improvements left in the comment of your gist, and this is my derived version: https://gist.github.com/felix021/0471fac31b84bf39d9acf98836aef9a7

Answer (score 0):

Download Etherwallet and run it locally, see my answer here:

[Problems with Ethereum Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/problems-with-ethereum-wallet/)

Its almost the same as above  answer, but even feels a bit more offline! ;-)